# Is this a legitimate use of a mixed conditional (present perfect in if clause, future simple in main clause)?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, if

Let's say I am describing the UI of a particular program. The name of the option displayed in one window (the window where the user is currently situated) depends on what the user selected in a prior window. Would the following sentence be a grammatically correct way of explaining this situation:

> If you have selected <name_of_action> in the <name_of_window> window,
> the option name will be ...

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: There is **no need** to say "If you have selected". You don't need a mixed conditional at all. Just use the present tense. But then, you need to post that right at the "end" of the first window.

Comment: Let's say that I can't edit the text describing what's going on in the first window. I can only explain the situation from this perspective, with the action in the first window being "in the past". Is the grammar in the example OK?

Comment: Yes, but it implies you have moved to that second window. I find it's better to inform people in advance rather than post facto. But, it's your choice.